# How to set up an url prefix to access to the admin panel and the strapi server

Tags: strapi

[image]

Here you can see the server.js file configuration. Apparently all is working fine but if I put in the browser the url of the admin panel: http://localhost:1337/aplicaciones/strapi_accuee/admin it doesn't work. This is the image of the error:
[image]
Can anybody help me to configure properly this url prefix (/aplicaciones/strapi_accuee) in strapi?

Answer (score 0):

`config/server.js` `url` is a `baseUrl` of your strapi project.
`config/admin.js` `url` is one that is appended to `baseUrl` to access admin panel.

so to setup it up properly, i would recomend adding .env file to the root of your project and set it up as so:

```
URL=http://localhost:1337
PUBLIC_ADMIN_URL=/myCustomAdminRoute
```

in `config/server.js`

```js
module.exports = ({env}) => {
  ...
  url: env("URL", "http://localhost:1337"),
  ...
```

in `config/admin.js`

```js
module.exports = ({env}) => {
  ...
  url: env("PUBLIC_ADMIN_URL", "/admin"),
  ...
```

```
yarn build
yarn develop
```

this would give you admin panel at:

```
http://localhost:1337/myCustomAdminRoute/
```

Api route:

```
http://localhost:1337/api/
```

## For http://localhost:1337/aplicaciones/strapi_accuee

i suspect you want to move api under `/aplicaciones/strapi_accuee/api` and uploads under `aplicaciones/strapi_accuee/uploads`

in .env specify following:

```
URL=http://localhost:1337/aplicaciones/strapi_accuee
PUBLIC_ADMIN_URL=/admin
```

and do:

```
yarn build
yarn develop
```

Comment: It doesn't work @antokhio. I actually want the api and assets to be in the route /aplicaciones/api/strapi_accuee and the panel admin in /aplicaciones/strapi_accuee. But even with your solution the panel admin doesn't work (not found error)

Comment: Have you did `yarn build`? You have to rebuild every time you do something in config

Comment: Yes @antokhio. I first delete .cache and build directory and after that I do yarn build and yarn develop

Comment: Well to be honest I tested it before posting on one of the project, idk if that’s a case but you need to have strapi baseUrl like /strapi and admin would be /strapi/admin, you can’t move this `/strapi` part, because there is many other routes strapi uses.

Comment: You can check the routes in use with: `yarn strapi routes:list`